# CSS zoom property not inherited with Google Chrome and Safari

Tags: google-chrome, inheritance, safari, zooming

I'm trying to use the zoom css style like this:

```
<div id="Embed1" style="zoom: 80%; height: 620px; width: 1180px;" >
    <iframe style="overflow:hidden; max-height:650px;" 
        height="618px" width="1178px" src="http://www.google.com">
    </iframe></div>
```

With IE9 and Firefox, the zooming factor is **properly transmitted to the page within the iFrame**.

But NOT when I use Safari of Chrome!!!
Of course I cannot re-zoom the content, otherwise I will have onlty 80% of 80% when using IE9 or Fox:

Does somebody knows a fix?

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported by all browsers. See the discussion here: http://www.css3.com/css-zoom/